# Volumetric Light not working on Cycles (but good in preview)

Tags: lighting, volumetrics

The volumetric Light shows pretty well in viewport preview, but doesn't render at all in Cycles.

4 point lights - Strength: 1000

A cube with a Volume Scatter / Density: 0.2 / Anisotrop: 0

I've made simple scenes for testing and it works, I don't know what is happening here, maybe someone has an idea of what could be wrong here?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your volume object set to render in the Outliner or Object properties?

Comment: could you share your file with just the volumetric effect alone?

Comment: 3pointedit / It was this! I thought I doubled checked that but no! Thank you so much! this is a dumb mistake haha.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the volume object wasn't set to render on its properties.

Comment: Hi, good! Maybe you could add some more details about how set it to render, and/or a screenshot, to help other users with similar issues...

Comment: Actually I think this answer is just wrong. "Properties" could only refer to the options on the volume node itself, of which none are even close to being labelled "render".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with volumetrics enabled,  but I put the volumetric cube to the collection where it wasn't getting rendered.

So check every object again closely, and make sure what should and what should not be rendered. I hope this helps.