# God rays in viewport but not in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

Trying to render a scene with a UFO with god rays coming out the bottom.

Working in Blender 2.9

In my viewport it has light

But in my render it doesn't

To get the god rays, I added a hole at the bottom of the UFO, and added a spotlight inside the UFO.

I then added a cube to surround that area, and gave it a volume scatter node like so:

[image]

My settings are:

- Light Paths > Max Bounces > Volume 5 (Tried 0 and 5, nothing happened)
- Increasing cube Density in the Volume Scatter node from .09 -> .15 (nothing happened)
- Toggled on and off Physical Atmosphere addon (nothing happened)
- Spotlight intensity: 100000 W
- Spotlight radius: 1.29 M (tried reducing to 0, nothing happened)

I also tried making the surrounding cube smaller, nothing happened

My render settings are:

- Cycles

[image]
[image]

My view layer settings look like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem was essentially what was described here: [Volumetric Light not working on Cycles (but good in preview)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120664/volumetric-light-not-working-on-cycles-but-good-in-preview)

So what I did was I selected that cube that surrounds the scene, and I went into the object visibility properties and selected "Render" because it was unselected.

[image]
[image]